# Send a parameter from an action to a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to send a parameter to a view from an action that resolves and sends that value. The issue is that when the parameter "arrives" to the view, it arrives null giving me an error when I try to manage it.

The code I have in the action is (it creates the parameter and send it):

```
public ActionResult CreateAccount(Account model)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _repository = new Repository();
            model.PublicadorId = GetPublicadorId();
            model.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            model.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
            model.IsActive = true;
            Int32 id = _repository.Store(model);

            return RedirectToAction("SubirImagenes/" + id, "Account");
        }
    }catch{}
}
```

So, the action that manage the parameter sent is (note that I pass the parameter as a nullable to avoid errors, and the name of the parameter is the same as the name I use to call the RedirectToAction before):

```
[HttpPost]
[AuthorizeUser]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult UploadImage(CompraVenta.Models.UploadFileModel fileModel, Int32? id)
{
    string directory = @"C:\Folder\";

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (fileModel != null && fileModel.File != null && fileModel.File.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileModel.File.FileName);
            fileModel.File.SaveAs(Path.Combine(directory, fileName));
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View();
}

[AuthorizeUser]
public ActionResult SubirImagenes()
{
    return View();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. The routing roules of my application is:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution. In the "get" action "SubirImagenes" I get the parameter and then, with a strong typed model, using a hidden field, I pass the parameter in the "post" action receiving it inside the model I pass as a parameter in that post action.

Answer (score 1):

You are using it wrong way, you have to pass parameter using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492939%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)  of `RedirectToAction()` which takes object of `RouteValueDictionary` as parameter.

Do like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("UploadImage", "Account", new {id = id});
```

### UPDATE:

you cannot pass parameters the way told above if action is **HttpPost**, the workaround is to directly call action without using `RedirectToAction` like:

```
return UploadImage(null,id);
```

Comment: I get a null value when I try to retrieve it in the UploadImage action. The url I get is http://example.com/Account/UploadImage?id=30. But when I read that value in the UploadImage action using the parameter id, I get a null value. Also I get a null value using Request.Querystring["id"].

Comment: it should work, may be there's some other thing you doing wrong

Comment: In the "get" action UploadImage I receive the value as id. But when I use the "post" action I lose the value being null the parameter. How can I make persist that value in the post action?

Comment: then i am afraid you cannot pass it using RedirectToAction to post method

Comment: The RedirectToAction pass the parameter to the Index action of the form (this does it well). The, in that form, I have a button that does a post (UploadImage), but here I can't get the parameter I receive in the Index method.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an anonymous object to the `RedirectToAction` for the action parameters:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new {id = id});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the method directly instead of using RedirectToAction like:

```
return UploadImage(null,id);
```

instead of

```
return RedirectToAction("UploadImage/" + id, "Account");
```

**Note**:- address in the browser would be of old method